# How to upload larger file than upload limit of my hosting provider?

Tags: php, web-hosting

I have hosted a domain name on a cheap hosting website. This website allows uploading only the files less than 50 MB. I want to upload larger files. Is there any working trick without changing in php.ini. because it's not possible for me.

Comment: There are some *chunk uploader* scripts around that include back end connectors for different languages including php

Comment: Instead of fiddling with cumbersome workarounds, find a better hosting service. Even a VPS can be had for 2 moneys per month.

Comment: @mario I have a better hosting service. But, this is an experimental one.

Comment: You may find that evading this limit gets your host to ban you for violating their terms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't really an easy way round this. A couple of suggestions:

- Resize images to make them smaller using Javascript before uploading. You can use a filereader and then a canvas to resize the image.
- If you really need them that big then split the images up into chunks, again using a filereader to get the file into Javascript, then extract the data in chunks and upload each chunk separately. You'd need some clever PHP code to stick the chunks back together again. I would add some kind of chunk index into each upload as you can't guarantee the chunks will arrive in order.

Comment: Could you please, give me an example?

Answer (score 0):

Since the max upload size is limited to 50MB you can't do it this way  , unless , you can split the file into  files less than 50MB and upload each one .

To implement this solution of spliting file into many parts , use [phpfsplit](https://github.com/ManZzup/phpfsplit)

You can also use the [plupload](https://www.plupload.com/)

Comment: It is not impossible. That sentence is very misleading

Comment: that make sens now ?

Comment: Yes...and plupload is one of the chunk uploaders I mentioned above that has a php connector also